# I am not able to bypass language question in cookieclicker site with my selenium code

Tags: python, selenium, bots

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("https://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker/")

actions = ActionChains(driver)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
language = driver.find_element_by_id("langSelect-EN")
actions.click(language).perform()
```

I found the id of the language, tried .click().perform()
but my code is not working to bypass the [site](https://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker/)'s language barrier. what am I missing can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone encounter this problem in the future use `from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By`

and the working code is like that

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

driver.get("https://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker/")

actions = ActionChains(driver)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
language = driver.find_element(By.ID, "langSelect-EN").click()
```

Answer (score -1):

Simple

```
driver.find_element_by_id("langSelect-EN").click()
```

should be enough - no need to use Actions

Comment: [21196:2936:0630/131501.714:ERROR:gpu_init.cc(486)] Passthrough is not supported, GL is disabled, ANGLE is     

---this is the error I get

Comment: @TalhaŞengül are you sure this error appeared because of my code line?

Comment: I don't think so, I think I should google these errors, thank you for your answer btw